# Targeting every 3rd, 6th, 9th etc element of a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, twig

I am using twig templating to loop though an array of items which would display as a grid with 3 items in a row. If there is an empty space at the end of the row I have a block that would be placed there, but only of there is one empty space. The below covers what I require but feels a bit clunky.

```
{% if items|length == 2 or items|length == 5 % or items|length == 8 %}
 // add a block to fill the space
{% endif %}
```

With jQuery I would do something like the below:

```
jQuery('#item:nth-child(3n+3)')
```

Is there a smarter way via the twig if statement to do the same?

Comment: How about `(length+1) % 3 === 0`?

Comment: {% if length is divisibleby(3) %} working for you ?

Comment: That's it, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can find every third row like this, am just adding here demo for the table row, you further can revise it according your need i guess.

```js
  $( "tr:nth-child(3n)").css( "background", "yellow" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10</td></tr>
    <tr><td>11</td></tr>
    <tr><td>12</td></tr>
  </table>
```